# Getting Ngram frequency from a a large corpus of txt. files

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

I need to develop a code for counting Ngram (1,2,3,4,5,6) frequencies in a large txt corpus using NLTK. I have two problems: 
1: I have the following code to import the files as bulk:

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader

Corpus_root = 'C/x/x/Myfolder'
files = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
files.fileids()
```

gives me an output of all my files read into NLTK.

My first problem is how to connect the corpus reader to the upcoming code to count the ngrams?

My problem in the next step is what module of code should I use to count bigram, trigram and four & five gram and their frequencies which is efficient and fast?

I have 300 txt files and want to use them to get ngram frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use your new corpus the same way as the built-in nltk corpora, like the Brown or Reuters corpus: By calling the methods `words()` or `sents()` as needed. Both methods accept a filename argument; if used, you'll only get the words of that file. I recommend using it to process the files one at a time, otherwise some of your ngrams will start in one file and end in another. (Do you want ngrams that fall across sentence boundaries? You must decide and proceed accordingly).

The NLTK book has functions `nltk.bigrams`, `nltk.trigrams`, and `nltk.ngrams` (which accepts a second argument `n` specifying the ngram size).

```
for fname in files.fileids():
    lots_of_bigrams = nltk.bigrams(files.words(fname))
    # count them however you want
```

[Chapter 2](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html) of the NLTK book shows how to use `words()` and `sents()`, and even has a section on ngrams. Take a good look.

Comment: Hi Thanks Alexis, Actually I want to process my files in batches and I want to have all possible ngrams (words) .